# How to hover one object and make it disappear then another object appear so I can click on it?

Tags: html, css

My first object is the one with class "dog-letter". it has two objects with class "dog" and "letter".I managed to make it disappear after hover.
My second object is the one black circle with class "dog-nose".
But I can't click on the this object after it appears.

*update*

after using `z-index:1`, the first object were giving consistency,but I still can't click on the second object everytime.
if i slightly move the cursor a bit, it can't be clicked.

```css
.dog-letter-box {
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FEEEEB;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.dog-letter {
  z-index:1;
  margin: 6% auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #00EFFE;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 50% 40%; 
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.dog {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  clip-path: circle(40%);
  background: #FFB6C1;
}
.letter {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: #FF46C1;
}
.dog-letter:hover + .dog-nose {
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: show-up;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  
}
.dog-nose {
  margin:10px auto;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #AFE1AF;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
.bounce:hover {
    animation-name: bounce-up;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
@keyframes bounce-up {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) rotateY(0); opacity: 1; }
  100% { transform: translateY(-15px) scaleY(0.2) rotateY(540deg); opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes show-up {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="dog-letter-box">
  <div class="dog-letter bounce">
      <div class="dog">55</div>
      <div class="letter">66</div>
  </div>
  <a class="dog-nose" href='http://www.google.com'>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
</svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't explain exactly why but setting `z-index:1` on your `.dog-letter` will change the behaviour of the `:hover` trigger giving consistency. In short the element will be responsive to the event on whole its area instead of what would happen if you don't make it stand above changing its z-index. You can also drop all your animation and just stick with a border set on `.dog-letter:hover` .. this alone will show the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code dependent on hover .dog-letter that not good and you can run animate on hover a box that include both of them(.dog-letter,.dog-nose).
I use .dog-letter-box, you can add a new div and put .dog-letter,.dog-nose to it.

Furthermore I use pointer-events:none for dog-letter after hover that can hover dog-nose and click to the link.

```css
.dog-letter-box {
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FEEEEB;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.dog-letter {
  z-index:1;
  margin: 6% auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #00EFFE;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform-origin: 50% 40%; 
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.dog {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  clip-path: circle(40%);
  background: #FFB6C1;
}
.letter {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: #FF46C1;
}
.dog-letter-box:hover .dog-nose {
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: show-up;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  
}
.dog-nose {
  margin:10px auto;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #AFE1AF;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}
.dog-letter-box:hover .bounce {
  animation-name: bounce-up;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}
@keyframes bounce-up {
  0%   { transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1) rotateY(0); opacity: 1; }
  100% { transform: translateY(-15px) scaleY(0.2) rotateY(540deg); opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes show-up {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="dog-letter-box">
  <div class="dog-letter bounce">
      <div class="dog">55</div>
      <div class="letter">66</div>
  </div>
  <a class="dog-nose" href='http://www.google.com'>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
</svg>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is what I wanted it to be!